# Get loaded AdMob ad Destination URL in Unity mobile app

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

In our Unity mobile game, we are occasionally showing rewarded video ads using AdMob. It is set up just like the [example documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-video). This works great, until an ad comes through that won't let the user close it. We need some way to identify the offending ads, so we can block them. Getting the Destination URL or Final URL would be the most useful. (I am open to any other identifying information too) However, I haven't been able to find anything that says how one might gather identifying information for a loaded ad, from within the app. I also haven't found anything that says this either isn't possible or not allowed.

Is it possible to identify an ad that was just loaded? If so, how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use .addKeyword("") to get relevant ads only other option is filtering ad networks from Admob

```
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().addKeyword("game");
```